# Troubleshoot 3COM 3001 NBX ip_unknown problem

Tags: voip, 3com

Things are getting pretty desperate here...

My 3001 NBX from 3com (R6_5_20) has been working perfectly for months... Now it works for more or less an hour and then all the phones in the branch offices (one connected in wi-fi, 1 km distance and others using adsl and vpn) go to ip_unknown and stop working.
Phones in central office never stop working, anyway.

If I reset the nbx everything starts to work again but then after more or less an hour they're dead again.
Even when I have the problem I'm able to ping branch offices and use applications without problems so it must be something related to the nbx or the astaro security gateway 7 that connects the wi fi bridge and lets vpn client reach our network.
I just do not have diagnostic clues because from a "normal network" point of view the situation's normal.

Any hints about what I could do to find the problem?

Fair thanks to anybody who'll read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the wi fi bridge was losing a lot of packets dragging the whole 3com nbx to death